# Why do array names not decay into pointers when left operand of assignment operator?

Tags: c++, c

It is said in the C standard that

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
>   expression that has type “array of type” is converted to an expression
>   with type “pointer to type” that pointer to the initial element of the
>   array object and is not an lvalue.

So why does the array type expression not decay into a pointer when used as the left operand of an assignment operator, like:

```
int arrayoften[] = { 10, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 };
arrayoften = 300; //not valid
```

I mean, the expression `arrayoften` is not one of the three exceptions, so shouldn't it theoretically be converted to a pointer?

Comment: The C standard as no bearing on how the expression is treated in C++. What language are you actually asking about?

Comment: **"and is not an lvalue."** You can't assign a value to an rvalue (within limits)

Comment: But I have been told that it works the same way in C++.. Hmm

Comment: Different languages with different ISO documents. You have been told a misleading thing.

Comment: @StoryTeller I guess that I then have to correct my teacher who claimed this tomorrow.. Anyway, I cannot find something similar to this in the C++ standard - only when array type expressions _can_ be converted to pointers.

Comment: It's described in the standard conversions section of the C++ standard. The relationship between lvalues and rvalues is treated completely differently however, and covered by many sections of the C++ standard. [*"can be converted to a **prvalue**"*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.array), which as you may have guessed is an entire topic all by itself.

Comment: Assigning `300` to a pointer isn't valid anyway.

Comment: @StoryTeller are you talking about this "An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown bound of T” can be converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to T.” The result is a pointer to the first element of the array."? If so, it does explain when they _are_  converted implicitly, only when they _can_ be converted?

Comment: @Rocket - You are missing the point. **It is being converted** in the expression you wrote. It's not the conversion that's the problem.

Comment: @BoPersson I know.. That was a bad example, but the expression is still not decayed into a pointer, which should be the focus :))))

Comment: @StoryTeller what.... So is it only because that you cannot assign 300 to a pointer, as Bo also said?

Comment: @Rocket - You can, with a cast, if the pointer is **assignable**.

Comment: Conversions (implicit or explicit) are applied to the left hand side of an assignment only.  It hardly makes any semantic sense to do otherwise.

Comment: @StoryTeller Still, the quote from one of my previous comment about a thing that the C++ standard stated, was that the one you were thinking about? Because if so, it does not state _when_ array type expressions _are_ converted implicitly, only when they _can_ be..

Comment: It may work the same way in C and C++, but you have quoted the C standard and tagged C++, which is inconsistent and will just invite comments that do not help your cause..  I suggest you tag it C and/or explicitly as "_and does C++ behave the same in this respect?_"

Comment: That's because the C++ standard specifies when it does or does not happen on a case by case basis. For each expression, it specifies the conversion that will be applied to the operands if any. Which brings us back to the problem of asking how the quote from ISO C pertains to C++, it doesn't.

Comment: @StoryTeller I did not really get that. What do you mean, doesn't it state when array type expressions _are_ converted to pointers implicitly? I mean the C standard does and if this does not apply for C++, should the Standard say _when_ they are?

Comment: @Rocket - So, have you tried `*arrayoften = 300;`?

Comment: Is this expression correct for pointers? `arrayoften = 300;`?

Comment: @BoPersson, yea, and I know that this works, but I thought that the expression without the asterisk was not converted, but know I know otherwise.. However, now I am confused about why the C++ standard does not mention _when_ array type expressions are converted to pointers when the C standard does and if it is not the same in C++ and C, shouldn't the C++ standard mention when they are converted into pointer? I can only find statements about when they _can_ be converted. This is also what has been talked about in the comments above

Comment: Guys, this is actually a good (and subtle) question; there's no need to downvote it.  (Although yes, the "= 300" part of the question as stated was an unfortunate distraction.)  And AFAIK the basic answer is the same for both C and C++; there's no need to get hung up on that point.  (I suppose in the end the full answer might be different for C++ since the `[]` operator can be overloaded on a class-specific basis.)

Comment: what is the exact error message?

Comment: The symbol `arrayoften` is not what gets converted it always has its given type. Only when a copy (or a temporary copy) is made will the conversion happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of answering this (as @Rakete1111 noted in a comment) is to say that that an array on the lhs *does* decay to a pointer.  But it's a pointer value (an rvalue), not an lvalue, so you can't assign to it.

What's the difference between an rvalue and an lvalue?  An rvalue is anything you can compute, that has a value.  An lvalue is a value that additionally has a **l**ocation (that the compiler knows), such that it can be stored into as the **l**eft-hand side of an assignment operator.  (The term "rvalue" is therefore a backformation; it's something that can appear on the **r**ight-hand side.)

We can understand this better with an example: Suppose I have

```
int a[10], b[10];
int *p1 = a, *p2 = b;

p1 = p2 + 1;
```

Now, the type `p1` is "pointer to int", and the type of the expression `p2 + 1` is "pointer to int", so I can make that assignment, no problem.

But what if I said

```
p1 + 1 = p2;    /* WRONG */
```

The types on the left and right-hand sides are still both "pointer to int", but now the lhs is `p1 + 1`, which is an rvalue, but not an lvalue.  It has no location, it's just a computed value, I can't assign to it.

So, going back to your example, saying

```
a = p1;
```

is sort of the same thing.  By the language in the C standard you quoted, the expression is converted to

```
&a[0] = p1;
```

Again, the types match, but `&a1[0]` is not an lvalue, so you can't assign to it.

You can tell this is what's going on (or what *might* be going on) by looking at the compiler error messages: for one compiler I tried, the error was "illegal lhs of assignment operator", which I believe indicates that everything was fine until the compiler discovered that the lhs was not an lvalue.  Indeed, I believe that the error message from Ritchie's original C compiler was simply "not an lvalue".  (I should boot up my '11 and see.)

Now, with all of this said, it's only one interpretation.  That there are others is suggested by the error messages of other compilers:

1. "incompatible types in assignment"
2. "incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int[10]’ from type ‘int’"
3. "array type 'int [10]' is not assignable"

Compiler 1 is an older version of gcc, compiler 2 is a newer version of gcc, and compiler 3 is clang.  It looks like these compilers are (for whatever reason) not blindly converting the array on the lhs to a pointer.  Perhaps this is so that they can give a better error message, perhaps it's for some other reason, although it does seem to suggest that these compilers are adding another exception -- not explicitly listed in the Standard -- to the list of cases where arrays are not converted to pointers.

[As an aside, though, I'm not sure what rule these newer compilers are using to cause the lhs to remain an array.  It can't be, "don't convert arrays to pointers on the left-hand side of an assignment operator", because there are plenty of valid expressions -- such as `*(a + 1) = 10` -- where that conversion is fine.]

One more point this whole discussion brings up is that the deep intertwinedness of the arrays-decay-to-pointers rule is that it makes it *very* difficult to contemplate a future in which there's an extension to C that adds proper array assignment.  Any compiler that wants to make

```
int a[10], b[10];
a = b;
```

work, first has to figure out how *not* to convert it into

```
a = &b[0];
```

or

```
&a[0] = &b[0];
```

Comment: Wow nice answer! It helps a lot. But so when you have this: `*arrayname = 12`, can you say that `arrayname` is an expression of array type or pointer type? I mean, because `arrayname` as itself in an assignment operation is implicitly converted to a pointer type, right.. So when talking about the expression, would you say that it is an expression of array type or pointer type?

Comment: @Rocket Oh, no question: `*arrayname = 12` is equivalent to `* &a[0] = 12` which is equivalent to `a[0] = 12`.  Perfectly legal, will work just like that under any C or C++ compiler anywhere.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question in the comment above - I asked if you would call the `arrayname` expression an expression of array type or pointer type? So with this code: `*arrayname = 12`, would you say that `arrayname` is an expression of array type or pointer type? Like, would you talk about the type of the expression after or before the implicit conversion?

Comment: @Rocket Ah.  Okay.  `arrayname` is an array, so `arrayname` is an expression of pointer type, because it started out as an array, and none of the exceptions apply, so it gets turned into a pointer as usual.  It's a pointer rvalue, but that's no problem, because any time you have an rvalue of type pointer-to-T, if you stick a `*` in front of it, that turns it into an lvalue of type T.  (I may be forgetting one, but I think there are basically two ways to get lvalues in C: (1) use a simple variable, (2) use `*` and a pointer.)